# GRASS v.to.rast outputs a bounding box of the geographic region

Tags: grass-gis, rasterization

[image: Output raster]I'm trying to rasterize a vector layer in GRASS after setting the geographic region to the vector layer extent. I also used v.category to add categories to my vector layer. The command I'm using to rasterize is:

```
v.to.rast -d --overwrite input=nyc_census_blocks@may type=boundary,centroid,area output=raster_map@may use=cat
```

However, the output I'm getting is just a yellow rectangle of the geographic region I set, not the shape of my vector layer.

The region is:

```
g.region -p                                                                     
projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
zone:       0
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      40:54:55.917994N
south:      40:29:46.015423N
west:       74:15:20.12891W
east:       73:42:00.03263W
nsres:      0:25:09.902571
ewres:      0:33:20.09628
rows:       1
cols:       1
cells:      1
```

Description of vector layer:

```
v.info nyc_census_blocks                                                        


+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Name:            nyc_census_blocks                                         |
 | Mapset:          may                                                       |
 | Location:        newLocation                                               |
 | Database:        /Users/may                                                |
 | Title:                                                                     |
 | Map scale:       1:1                                                       |
 | Name of creator: may                                                       |
 | Organization:                                                              |
 | Source date:     Thu Mar  4 11:32:24 2021                                  |
 | Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Map format:      native                                                    |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |   Type of map: vector (level: 2)                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Number of points:       0               Number of centroids:  39250      |
 |   Number of lines:        0               Number of boundaries: 91570      |
 |   Number of areas:        39250           Number of islands:    107        |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Map is 3D:              No                                               |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:  40:54:55.917994N    S:  40:29:46.015423N                 |
 |               E:   73:42:00.03263W    W:   74:15:20.12891W                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
 |   Comment:                                                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What are your region settings? i.e. please post the output of `g.region -p` and `v.info nyc_census_blocks`

Comment: I added this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the added information.
Note that your region is set to 1 pixel by 1 pixel. The resolution (by default) is set to the extent of the vector, about 0.5 degrees (or approx 50 km.). In order to get a raster at higher resolution, just set a much finer resolution. i.e.:

`g.region -ap res=00:00:03`

That will give you a resolution of 3 arcseconds, or about 90 meters. Then redo

`v.to.rast -d --overwrite input=nyc_census_blocks type=area output=raster_map use=cat`